# Perl - How to create an array with the values of pre-existing arrays?

Tags: arrays, perl

I'm new to perl and to programming at all, so here's my stupid question:

I want to create an array from the values stored in two pre-existing arrays.
e.g.

I have **@array1** made of elements: **A, B, C**

and **@array2** made of **B, D, E**.

I want **@array3** made of **A, B, C, B, D, E**.

But I'm getting an array made of 1 single element which is an array itself.

I'm doing:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my @array1 = ('A', 'B', 'C');
my @array2 = ('B', 'D', 'E');
my $length1 = @array1 -1;
my $length2 = @array2 -1;

my @merge;

push @merge, "@array1[0..$length1] @array2[0..$length2]";
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @array3 = (@array1, @array2);
```

When assigning `(@array1, @array2)`, array elements of both arrays will get flattened into list and assigned to `@array3`.